# Socket read() function sometimes never returns 0 when processing tunneling

Tags: c++, sockets

```
if(port == 443){ // https
    strcpy(buffer, "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n");
    write(client, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    tunnel(server, client, buffer);
    return;
}
```

tunnel() looks like below

```
void tunnel(int server, int client, char* buffer){
    int servercon, clientcon;
    int x;
    x = fcntl(server, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(server, F_SETFL, x|O_NONBLOCK);
    x = fcntl(client, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(client, F_SETFL, x|O_NONBLOCK);
    while(true){
        cout << "test" << endl;
        clientcon = read(client, buffer, BUFSIZE);
        write(server, buffer, clientcon);
        servercon = read(server, buffer, BUFSIZE);
        write(client, buffer, servercon);
        if(???) // This condition
            break;
    }

    close(client);
    close(server);
}
```

I'm trying to implement tunneling when the proxy server receives CONNECT method.
This code works well (HTTPS websites are successfully loaded)
However, the problem is that the infinite while() loop can not be escaped because read() function sometimes never returns 0.

As a break condition, I tried several options.

1) servercon == 0 (Sometimes read() function never returns 0)

2) servercon == -1 (Secure connection failed occurs. I don't know why)

3) Add a variable i as a timer, and i<100000 (It works, but too inefficient)

How should I set the break condition?

(Make the socket non-blocking is necessary. Without it, the program stops at read() function forever. I don't know the reason, but making the socket non-blocking solved the problem.)

Comment: You're asking why does a socket that's blocking ... block?  You probably want to break the loop as soon as one of your reads fails.

Comment: @UKMonkey No, I just wanted to say by the last line that non-blocking socket was needed for me. Just in case that someone asks why I used non-blocking socket.

Comment: @UKMonkey I want to break the loop as soon as the HTTPS request+response ends. But the return value of read() sometimes never indicates that the connection has ended.

Comment: Are you sure the connection *has* ended? HTTP doesn't require a connection to be broken at the end of a request. See this to start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: So it didn't end. So your loop should never exit. So what's the problem? NB You must test for a zero or -1 *before* issuing the write, and you must error-check the write as well. You should also use a read timeout. You don't need nonblocking mode. And a proxy server must copy in both directions simultaneously. And error-check the reads and writes in both directions,

Comment: The correct way to do this (well, *a* correct way) would be to use `select` with the two socket descriptors to detect when each is "readable". If `select` tells you a socket is readable, then when you go to read it, you will either get data (return value > 0) or you will get EOF (return value 0).

Comment: @Gil Hamilton Wow, I have not known that function. I will try it. thanks

Comment: @Gil Hamilton It works, but still read() doesn't return 0. This is my conjecture, that EOF is encrypted together so read() can not recognize it, so it doesn't return 0.

Comment: @James your conjecture is wrong. The EOF condition is not encrypted. There is no actual EOF character in the transmitted HTTP data. The EOF to signal a socket closure is handled at the TCP layer instead. The most likely scenario is as Gil stated - an HTTP keep-alive is likely being used, so the connection is simply not closed at the end of the server's response. Using a keep-alive is the default behavior in HTTP 1.1 and later, to avoid unnecessary TCP and HTTPS round-trips when the client wants to send multiple commands to the same server

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Actually, I used HTTP 1.0 and got rid of Keep-Alive header like my assignment stated. Anyway, my assignment is only implementing HTTP proxy server, not HTTPS. Maybe I have to give up. It makes me frustrated...

Comment: @James just because your proxy claims to use HTTP 1.0 does not mean the client cannot use HTTP 1.1+ when communicating with the target server once the tunnel is established. In which case, HTTP keep-alive can still apply in this situation. Most modern web servers and browsers use HTTP 1.1 nowadays. And the primary purpose for a web browser to use CONNECT is for tunneling HTTPS.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Oh... You're right. I only modified only HTTP request headers.. I can't modify request headers in the tunnel. Now I finally get it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tunnel()` loop is completely ignoring the return values of `read()` and `write()`.  Try something more like this instead:

```
bool writeAll(int sckt, void *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    char *pbuffer = (char*) buffer;
    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        ssize_t numSent = write(sckt, pbuffer, buflen);
        if (numSent < 0) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            return false;
        }
        pbuffer += numSent;
        buflen -= numSent;
    }
    return true;
}

...

strcpy(buffer, "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n");
if (writeAll(client, buffer, strlen(buffer)))
    tunnel(server, client, buffer);
close(client);
close(server);
return;

...

void tunnel(int server, int client, char *buffer)
{
    int maxFD = max(server, client) + 1;
    ssize_t numRead;
    FD_SET fd;

    int x = fcntl(server, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(server, F_SETFL, x | O_NONBLOCK);

    x = fcntl(client, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(client, F_SETFL, x | O_NONBLOCK);

    do
    {
        cout << "test" << endl;

        FD_ZERO(&fd);
        FD_SET(&fd, server);
        FD_SET(&fd, client);

        x = select(maxFD, &fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (x < 0) break;

        if (FD_ISSET(&fd, client))
        {
            numRead = read(client, buffer, BUFSIZE);
            if (numRead <= 0) break;

            if (!writeAll(server, buffer, numRead))
                break;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(&fd, server))
        {
            numRead = read(server, buffer, BUFSIZE);
            if (numRead <= 0) break;

            if (!writeAll(client, buffer, numRead))
                break;
        }
    }
    while (true);
}
```

As for why your reads are not always returning 0 when you are expecting, that is most likely due to the client and server using an HTTP keep-alive to keep the tunnel connection open after the server has sent its response, so the client can send subsequent requests to the same server using the same TCP connection.  Establishing a new TCP connection, and even a new HTTPS session, on every HTTP/S request is time-consuming and wastes bandwidth as it involves many round trips for the TCP and TLS handshakes.  So the default behavior of HTTP 1.1 and later is to keep a connection open unless either party explicitly states a close is wanted via a `Connection: close` header.

Comment: Sorry for a late question. Is it possible that write() function doesn't write exactly buflen characters? (Can buflen be not equal to numSent?)

Comment: @James Yes, that is possible, per the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write): "*The number of bytes written **may be less** than `count`*", which is why you have to pay attention to the actual return value and act accordingly.

Comment: See: [FAQ > Reading data from a socket](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1044780608&answer=1108255660)